# How to run a batch file to run at any user log in to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-10.04, batch-file

Please help me create a batch file that I want have it configured every time any user logs in to my personal computer (there are couple of non-admin non-root users)
Another concern is that this should run invisible, i.e. no prompts, etc.

I want to have this command run invisibly at every user login to my PC :
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner anotheruser -j DROP

Basically, this command stops internet access for this user 'anotheruser'. And I want to have this command run every time this (or any other user) logs in to my PC.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't need it to run as root, you'd be best to write it as a script and put it in `/etc/profile.d/`. `profile.d` scripts are executed on login. However, since you need it to run as root invisibly, you'd probably either need to:

- Make a daemon to do it
- Have root run a `while` loop for user logins

There's probably some other ways too.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but you are talking to a noob here (sorry). Can you give me any directions on these, any sites probably which can help on these two options.